# Error: ora-00917: missing comma

Tags: oracle

```
Create table A_15006977.vehicle. (
       Vin varchar(20) primary key,
       Vehicle_type char(20) not null,
       Mileage number(20) not null,
       Manufacturer char(20) not null 
);

Insert all
Into A_15006977.vehicle(vin,vehicle_type,mileage,manufacturer) 
values ('tf1bb2ve533093891','panel van',18 325,'man')
A_15006977.vehicle(vin,vehicle_type,mileage,manufacturer) 
values     
('tf1bb2ve533093822','standard van',79 885,'ford')


Select * from dual;
```

Comment: Oracle thinks a comma is required because of the space in the mileage values - remove the space(s) and this error goes away. You should also have an invalid table name error because of the dot after vehicle in the create table statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create table A_15006977.vehicle (
  Vin          varchar(20) CONSTRAINT vehicle__vin__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  Vehicle_type char(20)    CONSTRAINT vehicle__vehicle_type__nn not null,
  Mileage      number(20)  CONSTRAINT vehicle__mileage__nn not null,
  Manufacturer char(20)    CONSTRAINT vehicle__manufacturer__nn not null 
);

Insert all
  Into A_15006977.vehicle(vin,vehicle_type,mileage,manufacturer) 
    VALUES ( 'tf1bb2ve533093891', 'panel van',    18325, 'man' )
  INTO A_15006977.vehicle (vin,vehicle_type,mileage,manufacturer) 
    values ( 'tf1bb2ve533093822', 'standard van', 79885, 'ford' )
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Or:

```
Insert Into A_15006977.vehicle( vin,vehicle_type,mileage,manufacturer )
  SELECT 'tf1bb2ve533093891','panel van',    18325, 'man'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tf1bb2ve533093822','standard van', 79885, 'ford' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note:*

- You had an extra `.` after the table name in the DDL statement and spaces in the mileage (`18 325` and `79 885`) which need removing and you needed an `INTO` keyword before the second insert.
- It is also useful to name your constraints (then you can easily determine which constraint has been violated in later statements).